# Find a string in a list of .odt files and print the matching lines

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find a way to find a word in a list of odt files. I mean a word inside the odt files.
Then, I want to see what files contain this word and the line matching this word (or at least some words before it and some words after it).

Here is what I have so far:

```
for file in *.odt; do unzip -c "$file" | grep -iq "searched_word" && echo "$file"; done
```

This shows me the name of the files that contain the word I'm looking for:

```
filename1.odt
filename2.odt
```

However, I can't succeed in seeing the lines matching the word in the files too, something like:

```
the is the first line with searched_word blabla : /path/filename1.odt
the is the second line with searched_word blabla : /path/filename2.odt
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Read the grep output into a variable and echo it using the same statement

`grep -i "searched_word" | read x && echo "$x:$file"`

```
$ cat filename1.odt
the is the first line with searched_word blabla
fsds
sdgdf
$ cat filename2.odt
gfdgj gdflgjdfl
the is the second line with searched_word blabla
fdg gdfgdf
$ for file in *.odt; do ; cat $file  | grep -i "searched_word" | read x && echo "$x:$file" ; done
the is the first line with searched_word blabla:filename1.odt
the is the second line with searched_word blabla:filename2.odt
```

Negative case

```
$ for file in *.odt; do ; cat $file  | grep -i "QQQQQ" | read x && echo "$x:$file" ; done
$
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, unfortunetely .odt files are zipped, so cat doesn't work with it. It has to be unzip first, which is why I wrote `do unzip -c "$file"` in the command I suggested.

`for file in *.odt; do ; cat $file  | grep -i "QQQQQ" | read x && echo "$x:$file" ; done`

gives: `:filename1.odt
:filename2.odt`

Comment: yes.. right, but you can tweak you statement i.e you can replace  ````grep -iq "searched_word" && echo "$file"````  to  ````grep -iq "searched_word" | read x && echo "$x:$file"```` and it will work

Comment: Unfortunetely `for file in *.odt; do unzip -c "$file" | grep -iq "Schengen" | read x && echo "$x:$file"; done` gives no results.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to let grep print your filename, even though you are using stdin. There are options for this:

```
   -H, --with-filename
          Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when there is more than one file to search.

   --label=LABEL
          Display input actually coming from standard input as input coming from file LABEL.  This is especially useful when implementing tools like zgrep, e.g., gzip -cd foo.gz |  grep  --label=foo  -H
          something.  See also the -H option.

   -n, --line-number
          Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.

   -a, --text
          Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.
```

So you simply set `--label=$file -Ha -n` and you get the output as if grep had been run directly.

You need the -H ... easy mistake to make, but without it there is "only 1 input file" so no label is printed.

You might need -a if grep's heuristic decides the input looks like binary.

Actually, why can't you run grep directly? Some installations of grep will auto-unpack .gz files.

Comment: THanks for your answer, but that doesn't work. Here is what I tried `for file in *.odt; do unzip -c "$file" | grep -iq --label="$file" "searched_word" && echo "$file"; done`

Comment: You need the `-H` ... easy mistake to make, but without it there is "only 1 input file" so no label is printed.

Comment: What about your `-q`?  -q, --quiet, --silent     suppress all normal output

Comment: If the file content is text then it shouldn't be after it is unzipped. If it is not text inside the zip, I don't see how you ever expected it to work? You can add  `-a` to treat binary as text. This is all in `man grep`

Comment: Actually, yesterday I saw the same issue - piped output that I thought was valid text, grep decided was binary. `-a` fixed it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

A rudimentary implementation in Java 1.8:

```
package app;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.Namespace;
import org.jdom2.filter.Filters;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;


/**
 *  OfficeSearch
 */
public class OfficeSearch
{
    private final Set<String> searchSet = new HashSet<>();
    private static OfficeSearch INSTANCE = new OfficeSearch();

    //
    // main
    //
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        INSTANCE.execute(args);
    }

    //
    //  execute
    //
    private void execute(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 1) {
            for (int i=1; i<args.length; i++) {
                searchSet.add(args[i].toLowerCase());
            }
            try {
                Files.list(Paths.get(args[0])).sorted().
                    map(Path::toFile).
                    filter(this::is_odt).
                    forEach(this::search);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Usage: OfficeSearch <directory> <search_term> [...]");
        }

    }

    //
    //  is_odt
    //
    private boolean is_odt(File file) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            final String name = file.getName();
            final int dotidx = name.lastIndexOf('.');
            if ((0 <= dotidx) && (dotidx < name.length() - 1)) {
                return name.substring(dotidx + 1).equalsIgnoreCase("odt");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //
    // search
    //
    private void search(File odt) {
        try (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(odt)) {
            final ZipEntry content = zip.getEntry("content.xml");
            if (content != null) {
                final SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
                final Document doc = builder.build(zip.getInputStream(content));
                final Element root = doc.getRootElement();
                final Namespace office_ns = root.getNamespace("office");
                final Namespace text_ns = root.getNamespace("text");
                final Element body = root.getChild("body", office_ns);
                if (body != null) {
                    boolean found = false;
                    for (Element e : body.getDescendants(Filters.element(text_ns))) {
                        if ("p".equals(e.getName()) ||
                            "h".equals(e.getName())) {
                            final String s = e.getValue().toLowerCase();
                            for (String p : searchSet) {
                                if (s.contains(p)) {
                                    if (!found) {
                                        found = true;
                                        System.out.println("\n" + odt.toString());
                                    }
                                    System.out.println(e.getValue());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException | JDOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```